# Can you create a mixed effects General Additive Model?

Tags: mixed-model, multicollinearity, generalized-additive-model

I'm facing a challenge with how to apply a GAM to a dataset. I'm using network data, pretend for the sake of specificity, between individuals. I'm interesting in the relationship between team size and the cohesion within the team (i.e. # of edges / # of potential edges).

My problem is that I have two sources of collinearity within the dataset. The first is that the dataset is actually 5 different networks combined into one. (These are from different social networks, so they don't overlap at all.) I presume that each network has a slightly different structure and so each team's cohesion is correlated with other team's correlation.

The second is that the social networks are measured over time, every day for a month for each dataset. In each case, the individuals stays roughly the same. So, we now have a time component - where each team's cohesion is sampled every day. Again, I'd expect there to be strong collinearity between the team cohesion on day 2 and day 3.

I'm trying to model the effect of team size on cohesion. So far what I created was a GAM with one smoother (team size) and one categorical variable (social network) and a logit link function. But, I realized that this might not take into account the collinearity of the teams.

Is there a way to make a mixed effect model using GAM? Or is there another way that you'd suggest approaching this problem?

Comment: Please check the package `gamm4`. It allows fitting generalized additive mixed models which seems to be exactly what you are asking it.

Comment: and also `gamm` from `mgcv`